# jquery [object DispHTMLWindow2] issue IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have an exception when run a jQuery application only on IE8.

I get an error "Array.prototype.slice isn´t a Javascript object" at the beginning of the execution of the webpage.

I tried to get more information about the object and i got from the debbuger it is an object DispHTMLWindow2.

Then i have tried to make breakpoints for all calls of jQuery on the code and i get the same type of object in a jquery ajax call. I tried to fix it without success.

```
function ajax(uri, method, data, username, password) {
var request = {
    url: uri,
    type: method,
    contentType: "application/json",
    accepts: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 
            "Basic " + encodeForIE9(username + ":" + password));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR) {
        console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
    }
};
return $.ajax(request);
```

}

encodeForIE9 is a function for IE8 and IE9 that code the ajax request in base64.

```
   function encodeForIE9(){
    if (!window.btoa) {
        window.btoa = function(mensaje) {
            return Base64.encode(mensaje);
        }
    }
    }
```

Any idea about how to fix this error ?

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: It is jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: @JeffWatkins I forgot that the callback is unicode. The return message have special characters.

Comment: @JeffWatkins Fixed!, I don't encode the URI in the ajax function and it has special characters.
Firefox and Chrome looks like do it perfect without encode.